# How to insert product and sum between every two consecutive elements in an array

Tags: c++, vector

In a vector, I must insert product and sum between every two consecutive elements.For example the
1 2 3 4 vector will become 1 **3 2** 2 **5 6** 3 **7 12** 4.

This is the code i did till now.

You can see that the function which makes the insertion is insertInVector().

```
#include <iostream>

void sumProduct(int a, int b, int* suma_functie, int* produs_functie)
{
    *suma_functie = a + b;
    *produs_functie = a * b;
}

void insertInVector(int &n,int v[]) 
{
    int suma, produs;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        sumProduct(v[i], v[i + 1], &suma, &produs);

        v[i + 4] = v[i + 1];
        v[i + 1] = suma;

        v[i + 5] = v[i + 2];
        v[i + 2] =produs ;
    }
}
void readVector(int n, int v[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        std::cin >> v[i];
}
void displayVector(int& n, int v[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        std::cout << v[i]<<" ";

}
int main()
{
    int n,v[100];
    std::cin >> n;
    readVector(n, v);
    insertInVector(n, v);
    displayVector(n, v);
}
```

Comment: Nice. But, um, do you have a question? Maybe a misbehaviour which you would like to demonstrate with a [mre]? If so, ideally make one which does not require reading input and uses instead hardcoded input data to make sure that the problem is demonstrated conveniently.

Comment: You seem to use the `&` for parameters in a somewhat random way. Whatever problem you have, I would not be surprised if it could be fixed by using more care there. Try to rubber duck the effect of how you use it, compared to the effect you need for you functions to work. I think I see more than one unneeded `&` and I miss at least one. You also seem to mix C++ references and C pointers for the same purpose.... Risky.

Comment: It's about the algorithm that i must implement to solve this problem. I can't find a proper solution to make it work

Comment: This is a homework assignment, this is how we do it at class.

Comment: Your code could be greatly improved by removing "competitive programming" patterns like `v[100]` and `(int n, int v[])`. We have `std::vector`, we have iterators, we have references.

Comment: If in your class you are taught the demonstrated way of using references AND C pointers.... find a different class.

Comment: Um, I am a beginner, what do you expect?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's a little to late to change my faculty so i have to do it how they ask.

Comment: As a beginner I expect you to take the [tour], read [ask].

Comment: There are no vectors in your program, only arrays. Are you supposed to be using arrays or vectors? This would be considerably easer with vectors.

Comment: i changed the question so now it mirrors my problem with the code that must solve my assignment

Comment: Show this code to your faculty and ask them whether the use of references and C pointers matches what they are trying to teach you. If they confirm you should of course go on doing so to get the credit. You can later pay for expensive individual tutoring to get rid of the bad habits you picked up in that class. - But I bet they won't confirm.

Comment: Please go into details about "it doesn' work". What are the symptoms? With which input do you observe what output and how is it different to the output you need?

Comment: The **fundamental** problem with your code is that you are trying to insert values into the array at the same time as you are processing the array. So you end up destroying the array you are trying to process. The simplest fix is to have two arrays, an input array which never changes and an output array which is a copy of the input array with the extra elements added. That's your algorithmic mistake.

Comment: Oh dear. I got confused by OPs misuse of the word "vector" and mixing of pointers and references.  Luckily nobody took my bet... ;-) Thanks @john . I stand however with my other comments, with the possible exception of "miss at least one".

Comment: Thank you @john i will try to solve it and come with an update.

Comment: If you find a solution yourself, consider making an answer here. You can even accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed some things in your code. One of the main things is that you can't insert in the middle of an array as it has a static memory (if you want to change only in the given array without using anything extra then you should use `vector` instead of `array`). So for this purpose, I have used an extra `temp` array and reflected those changes in the original array at the end. Also, I used `pass by reference` in the function `sumProduct` as I am not aware of the way you were using it; you can change it if you want. Also `n+(2*(n-1))` is the new length of the array which can easily be predicted from the question. Just check out the changes in `insertInVector` function you will understand the rest.

```
#include <iostream>

void sumProduct(int a, int b, int& suma_functie, int& produs_functie)
{
    suma_functie = a + b;
    produs_functie = a * b;
}

void insertInVector(int &n,int v[]) 
{
    int suma, produs;
    int temp[100];
    for (int i = 1, j=1; i <= n-1; i++)
    {
        temp[j]=v[i];
        
        sumProduct(v[i], v[i + 1], suma, produs);

        temp[j+1]=suma;
        temp[j+2]=produs;
        j+=3;
    }
    int n2=n;
    n=n+(2*(n-1));
    temp[n]=v[n2];
    for (int i=1; i<= n; i++)
    {
        v[i]=temp[i];
    }
}
void readVector(int n, int v[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        std::cin >> v[i];
}
void displayVector(int& n, int v[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        std::cout << v[i]<<" ";

}
int main()
{
    int n,v[100];
    std::cin >> n;
    readVector(n, v);
    insertInVector(n, v);
    displayVector(n, v);
}
```

> Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get a similar solution, after i made few modifications to my original code.

Answer (score 0):

User8411584 is completely correct in pointing out that you need to create a temporary copy of the array first instead of simply beginning to overwrite it.

Just a little addition though:

The term for the new length of the resulting array n+(2*(n-1)) can be simplified to 3n-2.